# Coinbase Pro API Authentication - Invalid Signature

Tags: python, coinbase-api

Hoping to get some help on making calls to the Coinbase Pro API.

I created a key, noted my phasephrase, key and secret, and am running the below Python script. The response I get is "invalid signature".

On the CBPro documentation site, when I try running it with my credentials on [this](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getaccounttransfers) page, I get a "Sorry, you couldn't be authenticated with those credentails" message.

I've seen some sources that encode to base64 and have success, and others that don't, but neither works for me. What am I don't wrong?

Code:

```
import requests
import time
import base64
import json

url = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/accounts/account_id/transfers?limit=100"

key = "key"
secret = "secret" 
passphrase = "pass"
timestamp = str(time.time())

headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "cb-access-key": key,
    "cb-access-passphrase": passphrase,
    "cb-access-sign": encodedData,
    "cb-access-timestamp": timestamp
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Welcome at Stack Overflow. Please specify how you obtain `encodedData`, without this it would be impossible to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Signing a request is probably the worst part of the coinbase api.

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/docs/authorization-and-authentication#creating-a-request) for it. some things to note:

1. signature is only good for 30 seconds so you have to hurry and copy / paste the encoded data and timestamp into the docs form.
2. the timestamp has to be the same value you use in the encodedData.
3. the non-pro api signs a little different so make sure you're on the right set of docs. [This one](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/api-key-authentication) I don't think works for pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble authenticating your requests to coinbase here's an example of what i'm using. You might have to change a few things but does the job.

What you're looking for in this example are the `HMACAuth` & `CoinbaseSession` classes for your particular need.

```py
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from hashlib import sha256
from hmac import HMAC
from json import loads, JSONDecodeError
from types import SimpleNamespace
from typing import Union, Generator

from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
from requests.models import PreparedRequest
from requests.utils import to_native_string
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry

EXCHANGE: str = r"https://api.exchange.coinbase.com"

ACCOUNT = namedtuple(
    "ACCOUNT",
    (
        "id",
        "currency",
        "balance",
        "hold",
        "available",
        "profile_id",
        "trading_enabled",
    )
)
PRODUCT = namedtuple(
    "PRODUCT",
    (
        "id",
        "base_currency",
        "quote_currency",
        "base_min_size",
        "base_max_size",
        "quote_increment",
        "base_increment",
        "display_name",
        "min_market_funds",
        "max_market_funds",
        "margin_enabled",
        "fx_stablecoin",
        "max_slippage_percentage",
        "post_only",
        "limit_only",
        "cancel_only",
        "trading_disabled",
        "status",
        "status_message",
        "auction_mode",
    )
)


def encode(value: Union[str, bytes]) -> bytes:
    """Encode the string `value` with UTF-8."""
    if isinstance(value, str) is True:
        value = value.encode("UTF-8")
    return value


def decode(value: Union[bytes, str]) -> str:
    """Decode the bytes-like object `value` with UTF-8."""
    if isinstance(value, bytes) is True:
        value = value.decode("UTF-8")
    return value


def req_time():
    """POSIX timestamp as float. Number of seconds since Unix Epoch in UTC."""
    utc = get_utc()
    return utc.timestamp()


def get_utc() -> datetime:
    """Construct a datetime object with UTC time zone info."""
    return datetime.now(timezone.utc)


class TimeoutHTTPAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """Custom HTTP adapter with timeout capability."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timeout = kwargs.pop("timeout")
        super(TimeoutHTTPAdapter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({"timeout": self._timeout})
        return super(TimeoutHTTPAdapter, self).send(request, **kwargs)


class CoinbaseSession(Session):
    """Coinbase Session handle."""

    _headers: dict = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept-Charset": "utf-8",
    }

    @staticmethod
    def http_adapter(retries: int = 3, backoff: int = 1, timeout: int = 30):
        return TimeoutHTTPAdapter(
            max_retries=Retry(total=retries, backoff_factor=backoff),
            timeout=timeout
        )

    def __init__(self):
        super(CoinbaseSession, self).__init__()
        self.headers.update(self._headers)
        self.auth = HMACAuth()
        self.mount("https://", self.http_adapter())
        self.mount("http://", self.http_adapter())


class HMACAuth(AuthBase):
    """Requests signing handle."""

    @staticmethod
    def __pre_hash(timestamp: Union[str, int, float], request: PreparedRequest) -> bytes:
        """
        Create the pre-hash string by concatenating the timestamp with
        the request method, path_url and body if exists.
        """
        message = f"{timestamp}{request.method.upper()}{request.path_url}"
        body = request.body
        if body is not None:
            message = f"{message}{decode(body)}"
        return encode(message)

    @staticmethod
    def __sign(message: bytes) -> bytes:
        """Create a sha256 HMAC and sign the required `message`."""
        key = b64decode(encode(API.SECRET))  # be careful were you keep this!
        hmac = HMAC(key=key, msg=message, digestmod=sha256).digest()
        return b64encode(hmac)

    def __call__(self, request: PreparedRequest):
        timestamp = req_time()
        message = self.__pre_hash(timestamp, request)
        cb_access_sign = self.__sign(message)
        request.headers.update(
            {
                to_native_string('CB-ACCESS-KEY'): API.KEY,  # be careful where you keep this!
                to_native_string('CB-ACCESS-SIGN'): cb_access_sign,
                to_native_string('CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP'): str(timestamp),
                to_native_string('CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE'): API.PASSPHRASE,  # be careful where you keep this!
            }
        )
        return request


class CoinbaseAPI(object):
    """Coinbase API handle."""

    def __init__(self):
        self._session = CoinbaseSession()

    def request(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Send HTTP requests to the Coinbase API.
        Raises HTTPError if response is not 200.
        """
        print(f"DEBUG: Requesting resource (url = {kwargs.get('url')})")
        try:
            results = self.__request(**kwargs)
        except HTTPError as http_error:
            print(f"ERROR: Resource not found!", f"Cause: {http_error}")
        else:
            print(f"DEBUG: Resource found (url = {kwargs.get('url')})")
            return results

    def __request(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Send HTTP requests to the Coinbase API.
        Raises HTTPError if response is not 200.
        """
        method = getattr(self._session, kwargs.pop("method"))
        response = method(**kwargs)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            response.raise_for_status()
        else:
            try:
                results = loads(response.text)
            except JSONDecodeError as json_error:
                print("WARNING: Decoding JSON object failed!", f"Cause: {json_error}")
                kwargs.update({"method": method.__name__})
                return self.__request(**kwargs)
            else:
                return results


class Endpoints(object):
    """Coinbase server endpoints."""

    _server = None

    @staticmethod
    def join(*path, **params) -> str:
        """
        Construct the resource url by appending all `path`
        items to base url and join `params` if any.
        """
        url = "/".join(path)
        if len(params) > 0:
            params = [f"{key}={value}" for key, value in params.items()]
            url = f"{url}?{'&'.join(params)}"
        return url


class ExchangeEndpoints(Endpoints):
    """Coinbase exchange server endpoints."""

    _server = EXCHANGE

    def __init__(self):
        self.products = self.join(self._server, "products")
        self.accounts = self.join(self._server, "accounts")


class Exchange(CoinbaseAPI):
    """Coinbase exchange API client handle."""

    _endpoints = ExchangeEndpoints()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Exchange, self).__init__()

    def get_accounts(self) -> Generator:
        """Get a list of trading accounts from the profile of the API key."""
        response = self._accounts()
        for item in response:
            yield ACCOUNT(**item)

    def get_account(self, account_id: str) -> ACCOUNT:
        """
        Information for a single account. Use this endpoint when you know the account_id.
        API key must belong to the same profile as the account.
        """
        response = self._accounts(account_id)
        return ACCOUNT(**response)

    def get_products(self, query: str = None) -> Generator:
        """
        Gets a list of available currency pairs for trading.

        :param query: `type` query parameter (unknown).
        """
        response = self._products(type=query)
        for item in response:
            yield PRODUCT(**item)

    def get_product(self, product_id: str) -> PRODUCT:
        """
        Get information on a single product.

        :param product_id: The `id` string of the product/currency pair (ex: BTC-USD).
        """
        result = self._products(product_id)
        return PRODUCT(**result)

    def _accounts(self, *path, **params):
        """Access resources from the `accounts` endpoint of the exchange API."""
        params = self.clean_params(**params)
        _url = self._endpoints.join(
            self._endpoints.accounts,
            *path,
            **params
        )
        return self.request(method="get", url=_url)

    def _products(self, *path, **params):
        """Access resources from the `products` endpoint of the exchange API."""
        params = self.clean_params(**params)
        _url = self._endpoints.join(
            self._endpoints.products,
            *path,
            **params
        )
        return self.request(method="get", url=_url)

    def clean_params(self, **params) -> dict:
        """Clean `params` by removing None values."""
        temp = dict()
        for key, value in params.items():
            if value is None:
                continue
            if isinstance(value, dict) is True:
                value = self.clean_params(**value)
            temp.update({key: value})
        return temp


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # we're using PBKDF2HMAC (with symmetrically derived encryption key)
    # not included in this example
    key_vault = KeyVault()  # custom class for encrypting and storing secrets to keyring
    key_vault.cypher.password(value="your_password", salt="salty_password")

    api_credentials = loads(
        key_vault.get_password("coinbase", "pro-coinbase-api")
    )

    # accounts:
    ADA: str = "your_crypto_account_id"  # ex: 8b9806a4-7395-11ec-9b1a-f02f74d9105d

    API = SimpleNamespace(
        NAME="pro-coinbase-api",
        VERSION="2021-08-27",
        KEY=api_credentials.get("key"),
        PASSPHRASE=api_credentials.get("passphrase"),
        SECRET=api_credentials.get("secret"),
    )  # not the best example but does the job as long as you don't invite hackers in your PC :)

    api = Exchange()

    accounts = api.get_accounts()
    for account in accounts:
        print(account)

    account = api.get_account(account_id=ADA)
    print(account)

    products = api.get_products()
    for product in products:
        print(product)

    product = api.get_product("ATOM-EUR")
    print(product)
```